# filter array to limited key in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React.js app and I have the following result returned from mongodb. I am looking to filter the result to only contain `_id` and `customername` array key.

Example: `{"Records": [{"_id": "6190d42febf87a4b4da5fcb0", "customername": "Henry"}, {"_id": "6190b608b17338658902ae0b", "customername": "Henry"}}`

```json
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "_id": "6190d42febf87a4b4da5fcb0",
            "customername": "Henry",
            "grade": "D",
            "entrydate": "14/11/2021, 05:17:30 pm",
            "reject": "10",
            "clone": "D24",
            "remark": "",
            "selectedprocess": "raw-material",
            "selectedcategory": "nitrogen",
            "weight": [10,30],
            "totalweight": 40
        },
        {
            "_id": "6190b608b17338658902ae0b",
            "customername": "Henry",
            "grade": "A",
            "entrydate": "14/11/2021, 03:08:53 pm",
            "reject": "5",
            "clone": "D24",
            "remark": "Mr GunGUn",
            "selectedprocess": "raw-material",
            "selectedcategory": "nitrogen",
            "weight": [5,30],
            "totalweight": 35
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: From a security point of view: you should NOT return data that is not required. Its for safety, simplicity and to save some resources. If you are returning everything then you could be making an app unsecure by sending some sensitive data. Also it becomes harder to manage data, especially in typescript environment. And a large amount of data takes more time and data to send and also more resources to store. IMO you should work instead on your backend endpoint to only send the data you need rather then doing it with ReactJs on frontend.

Comment: Thanks Lith for the suggestion. Actually the result is returned at the backend and that is why I want to filter out the result to only have array with key = customername and _id before send to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.map to achieve the required result.

```
var updatedRecords = records.map((record)=> ({"_id": record._id,customername: record.customername }))
```

The updatedRecords would consists of a new array that would only contain the id and the customername.

The preferred way would be that the backend handles this

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way I can think of:

```
const updatedRecords = records.map(({_id, customername})=> ({_id, customername}));
```